# How do I get meaningful error messages for nested scala unit equality matchers?

Tags: scala, equality, scalatest, matcher

I want to assert equality in a ScalaTest of case classes which contain an Array. (So the built-in equality matchers for case classes are not applicable.)
Example:

```
case class Example(array: Array[Double], variable: Integer)
```

Test stub:

```
val a = Example(Array(0.1, 0.2), 1)
val b = Example(Array(0.1, 0.2), 1)
a should equal (b)
```

Fails as expected. So I implement an Equality trait:

```
implicit val exampleEq =
new Equality[Example] {
  def areEqual(left: Example, right: Any): Boolean =
    right match {
      case other: Example => {
        left.array should contain theSameElementsInOrderAs other.array
        left.variable should be other.variable
        true
      }
      case _ => false
    }
}
```

Which works. The other option is to implement the Equality trait with == at all places of the "should be" and in case it is false at one place return false, else true. The problem with both is that when running the test I get the error message that both "Example" objects are not equal (if they are not) but I would like to see in which element they differ.

How do I achieve this?

Thank you for your help!

[UPDATE] In practice Example contains multiple arrays and other fields, I changed the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Considered using:

```
left.array should contain theSameElementsInOrderAs other.array
```

Reference: [Working with "sequences"](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#workingWithSequences).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I considered this but rejected because I have multiple fields (eg 10) in my class and I don't want to write 10 should statements for each check.

Comment: @DreamFlasher Maybe I wasn't clear - not sure.  I meant to suggest replacing `left.array.length should be (other.array.length)
        for (i <- 0 until left.array.length) {
            left.array(i) should be (other.array(i))
        }`  with `left.array should contain theSameElementsInOrderAs other.array`

Comment: ah thank you, now it makes sense, yes you are right, I shouldn't compare elements on my own, but use the array comparison. But I still don't get an error there?

Comment: I changed the question accordingly, does it make more sense now?